# React.js design practice for this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think I'm getting up to speed with React, but one thing I'm not sure about is how do best.

I've got a page with a three widgets on it. Since I want to have the same behaviour and style on all widgets, I wrap each component in a `<PageAreaTemplate/>` tag which takes care of the styling and layout. One reason for this approach is that I also use the inner components where I don't want the `PageAreaTemplate` or another template.

In `PageAreaTemplate` I simple wraps `this.props.children` in the components required for the styling.

Now I need to let a few of the widgets add a toolbar (different for each) to the header in `PageAreaTemplate` (if it's wrapped by a template). It's doable by cloning the `children` and adding a function `setToolbar` in `PageAreaTemplate` but that certainly doesn't feel right.

What is your experience is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly common practice to take in a child element, clone it and return it slightly modified - whether it's to add additional properties or functionality.

```
function renderChildren(props) {
  return React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      setToolbar: () => ()
    })
  })
}
```

This just extends the current child as you would say, `Object.assign` as opposed to manipulating the current child.

The function above should allow you to then add any logic required to ensure you get what you want - ie. checking the type of the component, or some property value.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now but it felt like it's forcing me off a good path where I couldn't use regular state changes to get immediate updates in the toolbar, so I had to set the toolbar manually on every change. But setting the toolbar in the `componentWillMount` and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function calls worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using the approach suggested by @kelly-j-andrews to set the toolbar on the parent component but it required a few more tricks to really make updates on the toolbar work and be visible (toolbar part of inner component) by setting the state of the inner component, since updates on the inner won't trigger a render of the parent component.

What I ended up doing is:

1. In the outer component (`PageAreaTemplate`) I cloned each child and modified it according to the example above.
2. In the inner component, execute `setToolbar` in the lifecycle function call `componentDidMount` to set the initial component
3. Since a click on a button on the toolbar changes the state of the inner component, I again set the toolbar (`setToolbar`) on `componentDidUpdate` to force a render of the outer component. Calling `setToolbar` in an earlier phase results in a toolbar which reflects the state before the update.

This may not be anything new, but since my problem was not only being able to set a component in the parent but also making sure the state in the inner component is properly reflected in the toolbar I answered my own question.

It still doesn't feel like it's an optimal solution, but again, it's working...!

Comment: Seems like your question, and what you were trying to achieve were quite different. Good luck.